# Reading shapefile encoding

Tags: c#, encoding, shapefile, nettopologysuite

I have to read shapefile and get all attribut value. 
I use ([NetTopologySuite](https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/NetTopologySuite) ) :

```
void readShape()
{
  AtlGeometryFactory geom = new AtlGeometryFactory();
  var reader = new ShapefileDataReader(shpFileName, geom.GeometryFactory);
  DbaseFileHeader header = reader.DbaseHeader;
  while (reader.Read())
  {
    // some work
  }
}
```

I have encoding problem with characters "é", "è", "à", etc ... I get this unicode symbol: �
If i change encoding, this symbol (�) became "?".

I can't find any solution for changing encoding of reader.

Is anyone as a suggestion to help me ?

Thanks